# Conditional ratio with group by in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sum, conditional-statements

I want to do a groupby on column 1 then get the sum of values from column 2, conditional on the value in column 3, which are then divided by the total sum in column 2, still grouped by column 1.

An example is given below:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4, 2, 7], 'col3': [1, 1, 0, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

    col1    col2    col3
0   1       3       1
1   2       4       1
2   1       2       0
3   2       7       0
```

I want to create a new column: col4. For this column I group by col1 and then get the percentage of col2 values where col3 is 1 divided by the total grouped sum of col2. Such that I would end up with the following result. ( I put it in fractions to make it easier to follow the calculations.

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4
0   1       3       1       3/5
1   2       4       1       4/11
2   1       2       0       3/5
3   2       7       0       4/11
```

I tried the following, but this does not work unfortunately:

```
df.col4 = df.groupby(['col1']).transform(lambda x: np.where(x.col3 == 1, x.col2, 0).sum()) / df.groupby(['col1']).col2.transform('sum')
```

**Edit | Extended example**

I extended the example as the solution provided by Wen only covered the above simple example.

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4, 2, 7, 6, 8], 'col3': [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    col1    col2    col3
0   1       3       1
1   2       4       1
2   1       2       0
3   2       7       0
4   1       6       1
5   2       8       0
```

**Edit | Possible solution**

I found a possible solution. I would like to do it in a cleaner way, but this is readable and pretty simple. Any alternatives to combine these two lines of code are still appreciated ofcourse.

```
df['col4'] = np.where(df.col3 == 1, df.col2, 0)
df['col4'] = df.groupby(['col1']).col4.transform('sum') / df.groupby(['col1']).col2.transform('sum')
```

Comment: col1 ==2 do not have 1 in col3

Comment: Thanks @Wen I changed it

Answer (score 0):

You may need to correct your expected output , then using `map` after filter

```
df.col1.map(df.loc[df.col3==1,].set_index('col1').col2)/df.groupby(['col1']).col2.transform('sum')
Out[566]: 
0    0.600000
1    0.363636
2    0.600000
3    0.363636
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! However, for an extended example it does not work as the Index columns could have duplicates. I provided an additional example.

Answer (score 0):

simple :)

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4, 2, 7], 'col3': [1, 1, 0, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['col4'] = 0.0

def con(data):
    part_a = sum(data[data['col3'] == 1]['col2'])
    part_b = sum(data['col2'])
    data.col4 = part_a/part_b
    return data

df.groupby('col1').apply(con)
```

Output

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0  1    3    1    0.600000 
1  2    4    1    0.363636 
2  1    2    0    0.600000 
3  2    7    0    0.363636
```